# Saving a Weka model to text

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I would like to save my Weka classifier model to a file that can be read in by other (non-Java) programs. The Weka wiki says that Weka supports XML export via PMML files, however when I try saving my model as a PMML type via the explorer, it saves it to a non-text format. Is it possible to save a model in some text format via the Weka GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the place in the Weka wiki where it is said exporting models to PMML is possible. However, I *did* find several links, which seem to indicate this is not a feature in Weka:

- https://list.scms.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2010-August/049539.html
- http://old.nabble.com/Weka-models-into-PMML-td15528516.html

Admittedly, both of these questions date from over 2 years ago, so it is quite possible things have changed since then. However, in a rapid Google search, all links seem to point to the fact that Weka is only able to consume PMML, and not export.